# Difference between Householder Reflections and Gram-Schmidt?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, orthonormal

In numerical QR decomposition, when we calculate the orthonormal factor Q of a matrix, what is the difference in results if we use Householder Reflections to normalize the matrix or use Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization? Which one of these methods is preferred?

If the results can be different, does it mean that QR decomposition is not unique?

Comment: Did you try to look at the wikipedia article? It answers all of your questions... ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition ) 1. Householder Reflections are more stable, 2. The QR decomposition isn't unique but can be made unique by introducing additional restrictions.